# Why is my UIViewController's view nil?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to presenting UIViewcontrollers programmatically, and I'm having some issues presenting its view. Here is my code:

```
override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
    let controller = instantiateUserStickersController()
    self.addChildViewController(controller)
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view) //This line throws the error
}
private func instantiateUserStickersController() -> UIViewController {
    guard let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserStickersViewController") as? UserStickersViewController else { fatalError("Unable to instantiate a UserStickersViewController from the storyboard") }

    return controller
}
```

Why can't I access the controller's view? I'm sure I set the storyboard ID correctly

Here's my storyboard:

[image: Here's my storyboard if that helps]

Comment: What error are you seeing? The `fatalError` from your example or a different error from UIKit?

Comment: Different. It's not an unwrapping nil error. This is all i get "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: Expected behaviour in that case, assuming `controller` is a `UIViewController` subclass, would be that if `view` does not already exist, it is created there and then. Is that view controller meant to invent itself programmatically or is it in a storyboard or NIB? And, as per Jonah, what's the actual error?

Comment: Controller is a UserStickersViewController, a subclass of UICollectionViewController I storyboarded. And I'm not getting a specific error, just NSException.

Comment: An `NSException` will contain a name and reason describing why it was thrown. Set an exception breakpoint and find out what specifically is causing this exception and where it is being thrown from.

Comment: I did that. I left a comment in the code where the error was thrown.

Comment: you might need to make a call to `super.willBecomeActive(with: conversation)` above `let controller = instantiateUserStickersController()`. It's worth a try.

Comment: @Danoram I tried that but got the same error

Comment: I get an error whenever I use `controller.view`. For example if I put `print(controller.view.(any property here))` I get an error also. But as @Tommy said, the view shouldn't be nil.

Comment: Try to add didMoveToParentViewController:self on the controller property.

Answer (score 0):

The `view` should not exist before you present the view controller to kick off its lifecycle. So only access the new controller's `view` once it has been [presented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present#):

```swift
self.addChildViewController(controller)
self.present(controller, animated: true) {
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view) 
}
```

This worked for me.